# Binding and unBinding a jQuery plugin after Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the jQuery plugin FaceMocion. It is initialized like this:

```
$('.facemocion').faceMocion({ (etc) })
```

Problem is that after an Ajax call, I need to initialize the plugin again, and when I do, then it is re-initialized in those classes where it was already applied, so I get repeated emojis

I already tried the following:

```
$(".facemocion").unbind().removeData();
```

I am trying to unbind the plugin and then bind it to all the .facemocion classes again. But it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Unless the plugin exposes some kind of 'destroy' method, there's no easy way for you to remove its event handlers, other than to check its source and manually write your own code to do it.

Comment: Yeah, I made some changes to the plugin to avoid issues.